# yield his biggest career coup

Tags: phrase-meaning

Kenneth Branagh Is Finally Processing His Childhood Trauma
Branagh made his cinematic name with vibrant interpretations of Shakespeare, but a smaller, more personal project may **yield his biggest career coup**.

Source: NYTimes

Does "yield his biggest career coup" mean "produce his biggest career success"? Not sure my guess is correct because my explanation doesn't sound very natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means a notable success:
[Merriam-Webster *coup*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coup)

> : a brilliant, sudden, and usually highly successful stroke or act
> *She pulled off quite a coup when she snagged the usually reclusive author for an interview.*